# My WebAPI request doesn't work when I ask for NoContent. What do I do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Can't for the life of me, get this to work.

```
 [HttpGet, Route("GetCategories/{id:int?}")]
 public IHttpActionResult GetCategories(int id)
 {
      var @event = _repositoryService.FindEvent(id);
      if (@event == null || @event.Active != 1)
      { 
        return new ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Nothing to show."));
      }
 }
```

When I call in Postman http://localhost/api/GetCategories/33  I get no response at all. I can step through the code, but the response is not given. It looks as though the call is throwing an error. If I change the return to be

```
return NotFound();
```

Then I get a 404...but I need to return NoContent (204). What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure it will solve your problem, but HTTP 204 `NoContent` is not an "error response" but rather a "success" response.

Comment: When you step through the code, does it return where you expect it to?

Comment: Yes it enters the correct flow, but Postman says "Could not get any content". If I change the response code to something else, then it works

Comment: return Content(HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed, string.Empty);  This StatusCode works, but i'd rather use a NoContent(204)

Comment: Why not simply `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);`?